# Recursive PHP function to find the first occurrence of key in array inside multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying recursively loop through my multi dimensional array and want to return the current array if they array has the key.

I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible but this returns strange type error is confusing me.

Inside the foreach loop, if the nested item is an array, then run the function again till it finds an occurrence of the key.

Scratching my head, can anyone see my problem. Thanks.

```
<?php
/**
 * @param int|string $key
 * @param array $array
 * @return bool|array
 */
public static function multi_array_key_exists($key,$array): bool
{
    // if array key exist in this dimension
    if (array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
        // return the array
        return $array;
    } else {
        // foreach array as nested item
        foreach ($array as $nested) {
            // if the nested item is an array
            if (is_array($nested))
                // run this function again
                self::multi_array_key_exists($key,$nested);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should *return* what the recursive call gives you, when it is not `false`.

Comment: I'm returning array if key exist, and the re-used function also returns false if it doesn't exist, i'm not quite sure where you mean

Comment: Please, provide us with the information about the error you get and the array you try.

Comment: I initially rewrote your code for returning the top-level array instead of a nested one with the key (that's why the answer had been downvoted). I corrected the answer for the nested array, but could you clarify which one should be returned?

Comment: I've comment with the array with, still not returning the array that contains the key `form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected your method. Now it works as you wanted. You also need to remove returning bool type, as it can be either an array or a boolean value.

```
public static function multi_array_key_exists($key,$array)
{
    // if array key exist in this dimension
    if (array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
        // return the array
        return $array;
    } else {
        // foreach array as nested item
        foreach ($array as $nested) {
            // if the nested item is an array
            if (is_array($nested)) {
                // run this function again
                $value = self::multi_array_key_exists($key,$nested);
                if ($value) {
                    return $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will give the wrong return value when the match is deeply nested. It will give the top-level child-array as return value, wherein the match occurred, not the actual array that has the property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I thought that was what the author needs. I've corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: And I reread the question and still have doubts that author was willing to return the nested arra, not the top one.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/351e07febe40144a4b8121f136e0e23791afca6c Doesn't return anything.

Comment: This is the array that should be returned `{"acf_fc_layout":"form","form":"5"}`

Comment: My bad. Forgot that in this case we should continue. Check out current solution please.

Answer (score 1):

When you make your recursive call, you ignore what it returns. You should inspect it, and see whether that call found a match.

Replace:

```
self::multi_array_key_exists($key,$nested);
```

with:

```
$res = self::multi_array_key_exists($key,$nested);
if ($res !== false) return $res;
```

(don't forget to wrap the statements in braces).

Only when *all* recursive calls return `false` you can safely `return false` at the end of the function body.

As soon as one such recursive call returns a match, there is no need to keep iteration in that `foreach` loop. You can immediately exit, returning that same information to the parent execution context.

Another issue, is that you declare the function to return a `bool`, but you want it to sometimes return `false` and sometimes an array (when there is a match). So that can't work.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/sbAgPeA i have no idea why it says undefined variable, still getting error. Just added error on the imgur link

Comment: I'm with ya on the theory I can see why i'm getting the error, it's a fairy simple array too

Comment: You need to add braces. Here is a running implementation: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/76d593146f33ff35722017db9047eece494bbda6

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5f2d4c0b1001b7cfdbd0e6b489ebc3c69ebc24ad found the error this is the same notice i'm getting.

Comment: This is the array that should be returned `{"acf_fc_layout":"form","form":"5"}`

Comment: I accepted the other guys answer as my last sandbox with his code worked, if you check our last sandbox I was getting notice errors. But thanks for insight and help.